# TensorFlow:Queue crashed after I add tensorflow debugger

Tags: tensorflow

I am runing my code onTensorFlow and I get stange value of loss.
Now I want to use TensorFlow Debugger to debug my data, but when I add debugger in code as following,

```
sess=tfdbg.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess,thread_name_filter="MainThread$")
sess.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan",tfdbg.has_inf_or_nan)
```

it just cashed because of no element in queue, and with following error information:

```
index_epoch FIFOQueue '_0_index' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128000, current size 0)
         [[Node: index_dequeue = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](index, index_dequeue/n)]]


Caused by op 'index_dequeue', defined at:
  File "main3.py", line 120, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "main3.py", line 99, in main
    data_file=FLAGS.imglist_file)
  File "D:\workspace\tensorflow-101.git\CAN\trunk\model3.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.build_model()
  File "D:\workspace\tensorflow-101.git\CAN\trunk\model3.py", line 106, in build_model
    'index_dequeue') 
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py", line 457, in dequeue_many
    self._queue_ref, n=n, component_types=self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 946, in _queue_dequeue_many_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_0_index' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 128000, current size 0)
         [[Node: index_dequeue = QueueDequeueManyV2[component_types=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](index, index_dequeue/n)]]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main3.py", line 120, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "main3.py", line 103, in main
    can.train(FLAGS)
  File "D:\workspace\tensorflow-101.git\CAN\trunk\model3.py", line 273, in train
    label_epoch = np.array(self.label_list)[index_epoch] 
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

The full version of code can find in [here](https://github.com/mxl1990/CAN)

Comment: https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/issues/338